# Where is the skeleton thunar.xml?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

I am using Xubuntu 14.04.  I understand that when a user logins in for the first time several files in ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml are created including thunar.xml.  My question is where do these basic files come from?  It appears that in /etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml are perhaps the base files, but these don't match what's in the user .config directory and if I change them, new users don't get the new versions by default.  I'd like to know because I'm trying to change some default settings to hide network drives and mounted devices.  I can easily change it in the GUI on a per user basis but I'd rather setup a default that hides these things.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg -S thunar.xml` yields:

`xubuntu-default-settings: /etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/thunar.xml`

This is possibly the settings file that you want to change. Beware that it will be overwritten whenever you upgrade `xubuntu-default-settings` package.

You might want to read up on `update-alternatives` to operate independently.